# Do While loop is not exiting its x<y loop despite x>y

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Sorry for the wordy title...

I have a (second) loop in long set of VBA code. The loop is this:

```
Do While counterB < 40000
    On Error Resume Next
    AppActivate "Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        counterB = counterB + 100
        Sleep 100
    Else
        counterB = counterB + 40001
    End If
Loop
```

Now, there's a similar loop that checks a different program just before this one, and it works just fine. Checks if the program is open, increments its counter (the counters for the two loops have different names), checks again, increments, rinse-&-repeat, eventual finds its program, kicks out of its loop and the VBA code proceeds.

But this second loop... it just loops. Over, and over... It steps into the `If/Else` just fine (so, it *is* seeing or not seeing the program called in `AppActivate`), but the `While` statement doesn't acknowledge that **counterB** is greater than 40,000.

Does anyone see what I've done wrong...?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you `dim counterB as integer` and use `on error resume next`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here but I can see you're not clearing the error once it's found - so once `Err.Number` has a value it'll never not have one. Maybe use `Err.Clear` before you `AppActivate`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your piece of code as far as the loop concerns; even if Err.Number is always <> 0 it should end eventually.

 Try debugging, execute step by step, with a 'watch' on counterB.

Comment: But the others are right:  if you defined counterB as an integer, it will go wrong.  Probably the counterB = counterB + 40001 will 'do' nothing at all, leaving counterB as it is.

Comment: And this, kids, is why `On Error Resume Next` is poison. Avoid avoidable errors, *handle* the others. Don't just shove them under the proverbial carpet.

Comment: Yes, **counterB** is `dim`'d as an integer, as is **counter**. The error was originally cleared in the `Else`, but the loop was still stuck. Running through step-by-step was how I caught that the loop wasn't exiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to explain the `integer` stuff *CLR* and *Jeeped* are talking about:

An integer in VBA is 2 bytes and signed (can have negative values), so the max value is 32767. If you try to write a larger value into it, you get a runtime error 6 (Overflow) and the value remains unchanged. As there is a `on error resume next`, the error is not shown, the value stays at max at 32767 and never reaches the value of 40000 - you are trapped in an endless loop.

If you really need `on error resume next` in your code, you should check the  Err.Number for specific values that you are expecting (and reraise the error or show a MsgBox or something like that).

Your code could look like:

```
Do While counterB < 40000
    Dim saveError As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    AppActivate "Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services"
    saveError = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0

    If saveError <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number = <ENTER YOUR SPECIFIC ERROR CODE> Then
            counterB = counterB + 100
            Sleep 100
        Else
            Err.Raise saveError
        End If
    Else
        counterB = counterB + 40001
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: **Brilliant!!** I just changed the counter amount to 32,000 instead of 40,000 and it worked! Thank-you! I'll change **counterB** to <4000 and set the `Sleep` amount to 1000 instead, that way I'll get the same wait-time. Thank-you for the info about how Err.Number works I need to learn more about that and it's specific values.

Comment: @rdplanglois: Glad you where able to fix it. A general advice: Always use `long` rather than `integer` data type. There is nearly no case where you need `integer` or where there is an advantage of using it. With  `long`, you avoid those overflow problems.

Comment: @FunThomas: Thank-you, that's *very* useful advice!

Answer (score 1):

While the discussion and the accepted answer explain why the OP's code failed, the whole approach taken by the OP is less than ideal.

This is how I would do it

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim saveError As Long
    Dim counterB As Long
    Dim AppActivated  As Boolean

    For counterB = 1 To 400
        On Error Resume Next
            AppActivate "Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services"
            saveError = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0

        If saveError = 0 Then
            AppActivated = True
            Exit For
        Else
            Select Case saveError
                '<ENTER YOUR SPECIFIC ERROR CODES HERE>
                Case 5, 6, 7 ' for example
                    Sleep 100
                Case Else
                    Err.Raise saveError
            End Select
        End If
    Next

    If Not AppActivated Then
        ' Loop timed out.  What Now?
    Else
        ' App is activated
        '  More code...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank-you Chris. Your code is much more elegant. I'm still learning how to code in general, so, "hack something together that limps along" is my general skill level at the moment. I will, however, save your code for future use, when I eventually get to a functional state...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as @Jeeped mentioned, `counterB` is not an integer.. try the following:

```
Do While counterB < 40000
    On Error Resume Next
    AppActivate "Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        counterB = counterB + 100
        Sleep 100
        Err.Clear
    Else
        counterB = counterB + 40001
    End If
Loop
```